# How to solve squid:UndocumentedApi on public method in package classes

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have some classes, which are visible only in package. After analysis I received issues related with missing documentation on public constructors/methods/types etc.

[image: Example class]

Is this a bug (false positive)? It seems to me that change from public to not public constructors/methods/types is senseless.

I use [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) 5.1.1 and [Java Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin) 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About methods, fields and inner classes:**

Having **methods** (or fields or inner classes) being public in a package-private class implies that **if extended with a public class**, the public members from the package-private class will be visible from the outside! Consequently, they have to be considered as being public, and therefore documented.

**Example:**

- *package-private* class **A**:

  ```
  package org.foo;

  class A {
    public int field;
    public void method() {}
    public class Inner {}
  }
  ```
- *public* class **B**:

  ```
  package org.foo;

  public class B extends A {
  }
  ```
- *other package*, class **C**:

  ```
  package org.bar;

  public class C {
    void test() {
      B b = new B();

      int f = b.field;          // visible
      B.Inner = b.new Inner();  // visible
      b.method();               // visible
    }
  }
  ```

**About constructors:**

As constructors of the package-private class are only visible from the same package, and these constructors won't be callable from another package, even through public child class, it's indeed wrong to raise an issue on them and it should be corrected in the SQ rule from the java plugin (see [SONARJAVA-1557](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1557)).

I would however recommend to lower the visibility of that constructor, as having it public is somehow senseless...

Comment: Great! I will change visibility :) Can you create a ticket for FP on constructors?

Comment: Added link to the ticket in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A public constructor should be documented, so it is not a false positive. 
You don't need to declare the constructor public however :)

Comment: The constructor is "public", but the class is only visible in the package. This means that the constructor is not available outside the package.